# error: no such module error when using command line tools

Tags: swift, macos, command-line-arguments, command-line-tool

I am using Command line tools for macOS project. I have `main.swift` file in my project. I want to run this project from the terminal, So i am using command like below from the terminal:

```
swift main.swift hello
```

It is works fine. I am getting "hello" as param in my `main.swift`.

But the problem is like when i am importing other class in `main.swift` like

```
import SwiftSPM
```

**then it shows error like:**

```
main.swift:10:8: error: no such module 'SwiftSPM'
```

Its working fine when running building it from Xcode in mac simulator. But not from terminal.

Please help here..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I am using Command line tools for MacOS project."  Then what is iOS tag for?

Comment: Can you please help me here for my question?